# How to use left antisemi join using OR clause in U-sql

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, u-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I want to use a left antisemi join using or clause 
Below is the script which i have tried but it is not working

```cs
@AllData = SELECT DISTINCT rt.age,rt.[ID],rt.Contractor_Name ,rt.Updated_At 
           FROM @rawtab AS rt 
           LEFT  ANTISEMIJOIN @distincttable AS dt 
           ON  rt.[ID] == dt.[ID] 
           OR rt.Contractor_Name == dt.Contractor_Name OR rt.Updated_At == dt.Updated_At;
```

Or how can we have data which is not present in `@distincttable` based on `Contractor_Name ,ID and Updated_At`.